# Loud fans - Dell studio 1558

Tags: fan

I'm having a problem with my dell studio 1558 were my fans are running very loud.

I never had this problem on windows 7 and I'm really struggling to find a fix for it.

I've tried other distro's as well and they have the exact same problem.

It doesn't seem to be cpu as nothing is using a lot of resources, I've tried installing ati drivers but then i keep running into other problems and the noise doesn't seem to go away.

Thanks for the help, much appreciated!

Comment: can you please elaborate on your PC configuration? and do you have a dedicated GPU?

Comment: Yeah it has an ATI 5740.

Comment: Please provide additional information only by editing your question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had fan problems myself on Lenovo Y580 Intel® Core™ i7-3630QM CPU with internal hd 4000 graphic, and nvidia gtx660 graphic card.

I simply changed GPU on Nvidia X server settings (proprietary driver) to Intel.

You can use Intel graphic installer , it works well on Ubuntu 14.04.